# adding requirements to Create User Spring Security in Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am using Spring Security in my Grails App.  I am trying to add a requirement to the create user to connect it to another domain.  I have added it to the User Domain but it does not show when I go to create a new user.  Other than the lines I added the content of the domain is what was generated through the quickStart.  Here is what I have added and the surrounding code.  I am running the  Spring Security Core and UI

```
String username
    String password
    //Added to connect user to comapny
    static belongsTo=[company:Company]

    boolean enabled
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired
```

I have looked online and even found a tutorial that adds it like this.  It is not working for me.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I am new to Grails and Groovy.

Comment: Please explain what's "not working". Did you try to create a User in the BootStrap? Did you try to generate the views for User? It's good to show the error that you're getting too.

Comment: Yes I did create one in bootstrap and yes I needed to create the company to get the app to run.  However when I go to the security console, to user-create.  All that comes up are the default options of User and Password along with the checkboxes.  There is no field to enter the Company

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am running the spring security UI as well

Comment: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-ui/docs/manual/guide/customization.html - you need to customize the view to show your company field.